# Getting Uncommited data in transaction in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I executed the following Query in SQL Server Management studio 2005 and I did not commit the transaction.

```
begin transaction tran1
insert into errorlog (errorlogid,OCCURREDTIME,MESSAGE) values (10002,0,'');
```

(data is not committed).
Simultaneously , in another query window,I am executing the following query ,

```
select * from errorlog;
```

But it is waiting for the transaction tran1 to finish (due to locks).

So I executed the query with nolock option(from another query window)

```
select * from errorlog with (NOLOCK);
```

But , I am getting the rows inserted and not commited by tran1. 
Please help me to get the rows, that are not inserted by active transactions in select query.

Thanks & Regards,

Padmakumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from errorlog with (READPAST);
```

From ["Table Hints" in  MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)

> READPAST
>
> Specifies that the Database Engine not read rows that are locked by other transactions.

That is, it skips locks (eg held by transactions) but otherwise reads committed data only

Comment: is it possible to issue select query with readpast and without any shared locks.I think, READPAST also issues  shared lock while executing the query.

Comment: @padmakumar: sorry no. NOLOCK will both ignore and not issue locks. I wouldn't worry about shared locks